# Changing state to a React checkbox

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I am building a basic "To Do" app, the backed is in Flask the frontend in ReactJS.

I would like to change the state of my checkbox if the users clicks it.
However, I am not able to do so.

I created a basic `onCLick` function inside my `ToDoItem` component:

```
onClick={()=>this.setState({
                completed: true
                }, console.log(this.completed) # This output "UNDEFINED" in console)
              }
```

**However** it is not working as expected. I was expecting that, when the users clicks the checkbox, the setSTate would changed the `completed` params from  what the API gives to true

I think that the error is cause by the fact that in my`Constructor` I pass `items` and not the state of each item. But I am not sure.

**JSON from Flask**

```
{
  "todo_data": [
    {
      "completed": true, 
      "id": 1, 
      "text": "Take out the trash"
    }, 
    {
      "completed": false, 
      "id": 2, 
      "text": "Grocery shopping"
    }, 
    {
      "completed": false, 
      "id": 3, 
      "text": "Clean gecko tank"
    }, 
    {
      "completed": true, 
      "id": 4, 
      "text": "Mon lawn"
    }, 
    {
      "completed": false, 
      "id": 5, 
      "text": "Catch up on codind"
    }
  ]
}
```

**ToDoItem.js**

```
import React from "react"

class ToDoItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.todo_data
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
          <div>
          {items.map(item => (
            <p key={item.id}>
            {item.text}
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={item.completed}
              onClick={()=>this.setState({
                completed: true
                }, console.log(this.completed) # This output "UNDEFINED" in console)
              } 
            />
            <br></br>
            -----------
            </p>
          ))}
          </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default ToDoItem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably want to use `onChange` as opposed to an `onClick`, but ultimately either should work.  It won't change currently because you are reading the value from `this.state.item[x].completed`, but you are setting the value to `this.state.completed`.

I would create a handler that changes the item's `completed` status in the state.

```
onChange={(e) => {
 const checked = e.target.checked;
 let newItems = [...items]
 let index = newItems.findIndex(i => i.id === item.id);
 newItems[index].completed = checked;
 this.setState({ items: newItems})

}}
```

This will duplicate the array to prevent direct state mutation, update the single item being clicked on in place with a toggled value, and then update the entire array in your state to change only the checkbox for the item being clicked on.

Updated to onChange.

Answer (score 2):

Console log `this.state.completed` instead. It looks like your value should be set correctly. You're just reading from the wrong place.

I'd also initialize your state with a `completed` key, and change your onClick to

```
onClick={()=>this.setState({
                completed: !this.state.completed
                }, console.log(this.state.completed)
              }
```

This will toggle your value whether its checked or unchecked.

However, this will not change your display, as you are setting the value of the checkbox to the value from the `item` but not updating the `item`.

A simpler structure in my opinion, would be to have a parent component manage your API call:

```
import React from "react"

class ToDoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.todo_data
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
          <div>
            {items.map(item => (
              <ToDoItem item={item} />
          </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Then in ToDoItem.js

```
import React from "react"

class ToDoItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      item: props.item
    };
  }

  toggleCheck = () => {
    let item = this.state.item;
    item.completed = !item.completed;
    this.setState({item});
  }

  render() {
    <p key={this.state.item.id}>
      {this.state.item.text}
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={this.state.item.completed}
        onClick={this.toggleCheck} 
      />
      <br></br>
      -----------
    </p
  }
}
```

Comment: Agreed. In addition to this and to help protect your sanity, you can use the React extension for Chrome or the usual browser developer tools (F12) to check the current state of the object.

Comment: Thanks. Following  your advice: if I add this.state.completed the first click is "undefined" but other clicks after the first click do output the right state. In addition, the clicks do not change the box from checked to unchecked and vice versa.

Comment: Your component is named `ToDoItem`, but looks like it actually manages all items. If this is the desired behavior, You won't be able to manage all your completed flags with one key in state. You should follow the other answer here and set the completed flag on the item itself. Otherwise, you can fetch your data in a parent component, and pass one item as a prop. That would allow you to set one completed key.